# How can I view hidden files in the Finder?

Tags: finder, macos, ntfs

I noticed that whenever I add files and delete them, their physical space remains on the disk drive. I uninstalled NTFS Tuxera and I still have the same problem.

So I had to insert the disk under my other Windows laptop to locate the ./#### files and delete them. I was surprised that I couldn't locate those files in Finder, but windows allowed me to view them.

Is there a way to have more control over what files are viewed in Finder?

Platform: retina MacBook Pro, Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8)

Comment: The fact that you couldn't see them in Finder is normal, by default, the files that start with a dot are not shown.

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your first question, but feel free to ask it separately. If you do, though, you might want to explain what Tuxera NTFS *is* and *does* if you're looking for a replacement for it (and what would make that replacement "better" to you).

Comment: If you'd like to see ⇧⌘. (added in Snow Leopard for open and save dialogs) work in Finder too, head over to http://bugreport.apple.com and file a duplicate of radar://7096650. (Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/32612 for more answers.)

Comment: As of macOS 10.12,  Finder supports ⇧⌘. to toggle visibility of hidden files.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To enable the Finder to show all files (including "hidden" ones), you can type the following command in at the command prompt in **Terminal**:

`defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool YES; killall -HUP Finder`
The first part sets a hidden preference so the finder shows all files; the second part restarts the Finder so these preferences take effect (killall on its own tells a program to quit; the -HUP flag asks the program to restart).

If you want to reverse this so that the Finder now hides the files it normally hides, type this in Terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool NO; killall -HUP Finder`

That said, your actual problem of disk space not being freed up when you "delete" files is actually by design.

To permanently delete a file, you need to empty the Trash — Mac OS X doesn't delete files directly in the Finder; it first moves them to a temporary storage on their original volume, and then when you **Empty Trash…** in Finder, the files get deleted.

Some users are reporting that `defaults write com.apple.Finder` is not working on their Mountain Lion systems but `defaults write com.apple.finder` (note the lower case) is working. On my system running Mountain Lion, I am finding that the command works as written, but if it doesn't for you, try lower-casing the F in Finder in defaults write statement.

Comment: Legend, thanks alot. And thanks for the edit, I had a feeling that 2 questions in one are frowned upon. Btw is there a way I can toggle the terminal command ? Through an app of some sort or keyboard shortcut ?

Comment: @Daniel: Two questions for you: One, I normally type `TRUE`/`FALSE` instead of `Yes`/`No`. Does OSX recognize both? Two, what is `-HUP` used for?

Comment: See edits to the answer, and yes, both true/false and yes/no work for booleans.

Comment: Just my two cents here: I've used this toggle many times (probably should've aliased or scripted it by now) and have never used the HUP flag combo. Killall Finder has always worked on its own for me (running 10.6.8 on late 08 MBP).

Comment: the HUP flag to killall sends a gentler quit request to the Finder — if it's in the middle of something sensitive, killall -HUP is less likely to corrupt the filesystem, etc. than an unmodified killall (or killall -9)

Comment: HUP does not infer a restart. HUP is short for Hangup, you're right that it means the process should clean up after itself and quit. The fact that it comes back is the result of another process management system restarting the Finder automatically. If you were to HUP any third party program it would not come back.

Comment: @JasonSalaz I was imprecise in my description. You are, of course, correct that it is really a quit request, not a restart request, but that the Finder behaves differently because of a process that checks to be sure the Finder is running and if it is not, respawns it.

Comment: The command as mentioned above did not work for me on mountain lion. This worked however "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true"

Comment: One gotcha:  This works only on your account.  It is not a system wide setting.  Took me a while to figure out that it wasn't working because I had run it in a sudo shell.

Comment: Here is the command for Yosemite: defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean true ; killall Finder . Note the difference bool/boolean.

Comment: Daniel - I edited this as I agree with the flag on potential malware once removed. Thoughts on removing secrets entirely as it’s not looking like it’s maintained?

Answer (score 18):

You can also create a service like this in Automator:

[image]

```
[[ $(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles) = 1 ]] && b=false || b=true
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool $b
killall Finder
open -a Finder
```

Then give it a shortcut from System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services.

Comment: you should add the "-HUP" option if you want to restart Finder straight away

Answer (score 17):

For Open/Save dialogs, you can do <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>.

This should toggle hidden files visibility.

Comment: This is an excellent answer... Saved me a lot of trouble..

Comment: This is what I was looking for/thought I remembered...but didn't know it only applied to Open/Save :( +1

Answer (score 6):

Simple and faster:

1. In Finder click on **Go**
2. Hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> key and hidden directories & files will appear.
3. Click on required directory or file.

Comment: This shows 'Library' when in the Go menu, I can't see any way to make this work in the main Finder window panes

Comment: Even I can't see the hidden files using this.

Comment: This didn't show hidden FILES

Answer (score 5):

Run these commands to show hidden files

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool TRUE
killall Finder
```

These for hiding

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool FALSE
killall Finder
```

**Note**: `f` in `com.apple.finder` is small & `F` in `Finder` is capital.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The [required bool qualifier is missing](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174710/how-to-show-hidden-files-in-finder).

Comment: It's working absolutely perfect on `10.10.2`. I don't know why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler, safer.

In the finder menu bar select "Go/Go to folder...". Type the path to the invisible folder, in this case the top directory first slash of /folderName/ and it will reveal all inside it without using the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a Mac OS X app *"Show Time"* to quickly hide and show hidden files from the menubar.

It is open source and available on GitHub.

Check out the source [here](https://github.com/JamesMarino/ShowTime) and the release [here](https://github.com/JamesMarino/ShowTime/releases).

Answer (score 1):

One simple way that no one seemed to mention here: press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> while in Finder.

Comment: Correct, the other answers either don't use shortcuts are say they only work in certain dialogs boxes. The sequence you suggest works in ordinary Finder windows, too.

Comment: This key combo does absolutely nothing under macOS Sonoma (14.x).  `CMD-SHIFT-.` however shows some of the hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option of using [Mountain Tweaks](http://tweaksapp.com/app/mountain-tweaks/).

This has a function that where you can simply turn on or off view invisible files, but it has a limitation and it will only show hidden files on the os you are currently booting from.

So for example you wish to copy a file from a hidden directory on your booted os to a connected disk and its hidden directory you will not see it on the "targeted" disk but you will see it on the one you are booting/working from.

This came up on me when I was transferring some mail files to a new hdd in my MBP that I was upgrading to.
But if you simply wish to see hidden files its a nice feature and the [Mountain Tweaks](http://tweaksapp.com/app/mountain-tweaks/) app has some other very nice features as well, but it is a third party app and in my case the terminal way is an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `Spotlight` search for the file, when it is highlighted press and hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> and the path will appear at the bottom of the highlighted file.

Comment: How does this help in the situation described in the question?