# How to show hidden files in finder?

Tags: terminal, macos

In terminal I ran:

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`

and

`killall Finder`

If I <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>  `/usr/local/.git` I can see the folder.

However, if I <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and go to `/usr/local` I cannot see the folder.

Comment: <kbd> the key </kbd>

Comment: you mean /usr/local/git, without using the (.) so not the /usr/local/.git

Comment: @Buscar웃 I'm using a (.).  The OP is correct as is.  Now if that's the correct way to do it I dunno :)

Comment: normally system wont let you use a (.) in front of a folder or file name. You can’t use a name that begins with a dot “.”, because these names are reserved for the system. Please choose another name.

Comment: This is not a folder I created.  It is a convention used by Git.  The particular folder is part of the [homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md#formula-cookbook) project.

Comment: @bmike FWIW, this question points out an error on that SE page and some blogs on the internet.  `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` **does not work**.  The bool option is necessary.

Comment: Indeed. That is why it wasn't merged or deleted, just linked. Your comment on the wrong answer is awesome. I'll link here from there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to let Finder know that you want a Boolean value (true or false):

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Shift-Command-Period shows and hides the files in open/save dialogs, it might work in the main Finder.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: Works for me on Sierra, but it might have been added fairly recently.